# Reading and writing file between GCS bucket and Dataflow VM

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read file from GCS bucket (with path: gs://bucket_name), and load it to Dataflow VM folder(with path /tmp/file name).

Also I need to copy another file from Dataflow VM folder back to GCS bucket.

I have tried apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio library, but it not seems to work.

Can anyone give any suggestion on this?

Comment: Just to clarify my wording, I dont want to read line by line, basically what I want to do is to copy file from GCS bucket to DataflowVM, and also copy file from DataflowVM to GCS bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do it is to trigger a custom `DoFn` with the `process` method calling into the [GCS Python API](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html). The DoFn can be triggered by sending in elements to the `DoFn`. It can be triggered either by an Impulse (only execute once) or a PCollection (execute per element in the PCollection). Take a look [here](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/python-upload-files-download-files-google-cloud-storage/) for downloading/uploading blobs and [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html) for the GCS Python Client library docs.

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from google.cloud import storage

p = beam.Pipeline(...)
impulse = p | beam.Impulse()

class ReadWriteToGcs(beam.DoFn):
  def setup(self, e):
    self.client = storage.Client()

  def process(self, e):
    bucket = self.client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```